# PHP PDO connection to MySQL fails, mysql_connect works fine

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to connect to remote MySQL database using PDO, but it fails with error:

```
Connection failed: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'my_user'@'some.ip.address' (using password: YES)
```

This is how I'm trying to connect:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=sql.my_domain.nazwa.pl;dbname=my_db;port:3307";
$user = "my_user";
$password = "my_password";

try {
    $this->db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

and it fails. 
But this way:

```
mysql_connect('sql.my_domain.nazwa.pl:3307', 'my_user', 'my_password');
```

works fine.

Anyone have any idea what can be wrong with PDO, its configuration, parameters I set or maybe this specific server (nazwa.pl)?

[SOLVED] Ok, so that was simple (but also tricky to notice...) syntax error, it should be a `=` instead of `:` in `port` part of `dsn`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=sql.my_domain.nazwa.pl;dbname=my_db;port:3307";
```

with

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=sql.my_domain.nazwa.pl;dbname=my_db; port=3307";
```

Comment: @PeeHaa A formatting thing? I have always used a PDO on the same PC as Apache, but the docs that I found implied the syntax as above.

Comment: That's embarrassing... I didn't notice, that after 'port' should stay '=' not ':'. Now it works.
So thank you very much, that's the right answer.

Comment: @Fluffeh If you mean "Good luck" it should be "Powodzenia" :)

Comment: @zelazowy hehe, yeah, can't spell at all sadly, but can read oka-ish. Good luck either way :)

Comment: @Fluffeh Aha now I see the difference :-)

Comment: @Fluffeh I appreciate, that you tried to say it in my language, thats very nice :)

Comment: @PeeHaa Yeah, that was tricky to notice the difference, I didn't saw it until I pasted correct string into my project ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to connect to database on some other server Make sure your Sql server gives you the access on the particular port in your case 3307 from the IP address of the places where your codes are hosted.
If the both the servers are same try with localhost or 127.0.0.1